# jest mock implementation is not working with require('')

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to test one JS which is using one 3rd lib to fetch data, so I am using jest mock that implementation. It is working when I call it directly in the test. However, it is not working when it is used in source code.

Here is the code

```
//Source implementation

var reference = require('./reference');

module.exports = {
  getResult: function() {
    return reference.result();
  }
};


//Test code

jest.dontMock('./foo');
jest.dontMock('console');

describe('descirbe', function() {
  var foo = require('./foo');

  it('should ', function() {
    var reference = require('./reference');

    reference.result.mockImplementation(function (a, b, c) {
      return '123'
    });

    console.log(foo.getResult()); // undefined
    console.log(reference.result()); // 123
  });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your order of requires are wrong. When you require `./foo` before setting up your mock `reference` then `foo`s `reference` will be undefined as per Jest automocking.

```
jest.dontMock('./foo');                                                                                                                                                                                                                

describe('describe', function() {                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    it('should ', function () {                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        var reference = require('./reference');                                                                                                                                                                                               
        reference.result.mockImplementation(function (a, b, c) {
            return '123';
        });                                                                                                                                                                                               
        var foo = require('./foo');                                                                                                                                                                                                        

       console.log('ferr', foo.getResult());  // ferr 123                                                                                                                                                                                                
    });                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The line

`var foo = require('./foo');`

gets evaluated in the `describe` and stored in `foo`.

Afterwards, in the `it` block, you're mocking that out, but this isn't applying to the old reference `foo`.

Putting `foo` after the `mockImplementation` call will fix the error.

```
//Test code

jest.dontMock('./foo');
jest.dontMock('console');


describe('describe', function() {

  it('should ', function() {
    var reference = require('./reference');

    reference.result.mockImplementation(function (a, b, c) {
      return '123'
    });
    var foo = require('./foo');

    console.log(foo.getResult()); // undefined
    console.log(reference.result()); // 123
  });

});
```